# PHP explode/split with 2 different delimiters

Tags: php, string, split, explode

In the following string `$str` I need to explode/split the data get the part 'abc' and the **first** occurrence of '::' and then implode it all back together to a single string. Can the explode be done in one step instead of two consecutive explodes?

Example strings to work with:

```
$str="12345:hello abcdef123:test,demo::example::12345";
```

and the desired substring

```
$substr = "abcdef123:test,demo::"
```

Comment: Exploding with 2 delimiters could be done with `preg_split()`: `$sub = preg_split(',|:', $str);`, but the desired output doesn't make sense to me. Can you explain the logic behind it ?

Comment: The data is a complex array from a Wordpress db. I need to extract a part of it, edit the data and update the db with the new data. The only way I can think of doing it is to split the string, edit the "middle" part and implode it back together.

Comment: So the delimiters are `:` and you want to "stop" by `::` and get `xxx:yyy::` value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
preg_match('~\s\Kabc\S+?::~', $str , $match);
$result = $match[0];
```

or in a more explicit way

```
preg_match('~\s\Kabc\w*+:\w++(?>,\w++)*+::~', $str , $match);
$result = $match[0];
```

explanation:

first pattern:

```
~ : delimiter of the pattern
\s : any space or tab or newline (something blank)
\K : forget all that you have matched before
abc : your prefix
\S+? : all chars that are not in \s one or more time (+) without greed (?) 
     : (must not eat the :: after)
~ : ending delimiter
```

second pattern:

```
begin like the first
\w*+ : any chars in [a-zA-Z0-9] zero or more time with greed (*) and the 
     : RE engine don't backtrack when fail (+) 
     : (make the previous quantifier * "possessive")
":"  : like in the string
\w++ : same as previous but one or more time
(?> )*+ : atomic non capturing group (no backtrack inside) zero or more time 
     : with greed and possessive *+ (no backtrack)
"::" : like in the string
~    : ending delimiter
```

Comment: I'm terrible when it comes to regular expressions. This is what I'm getting: `Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '~' found`

Comment: @bikey77: i have forgotten the ending ~. Oops

Comment: Thanks, it works for the example where the delimiter is ::, doesnt work with }} which I will also need. Can you please tell me how to change the regex accordingly?

Comment: @bikey77: replace :: with \}\} cause curly braces are special characters in a regex pattern

Comment: Maybe, instead, you could explain the regular expression you have written and I can do the testing? That would be easier and better for both.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way, but since I avoid regular expression like bad tennis player avoids their backhand...

```
<?php
list($trash,$keep)=explode('abc',$str);
$keep='abc'.$keep;
list($substring,$trash)=explode('::',$keep);
$substring.='::'; //only if you want to force the double colon on the end.
?>
```

Comment: I've edited my example string to make it clear that there wont always be a :: before abc.

Comment: Will it always start with "abc"?

Comment: I edited my answer, but in the meantime, Casimir might have solved it the 'right' way. You might want some testing in there to make sure the double colon did actually exist.