# Exploding a String with Two Delimiters

Tags: php, arrays, string

First off, I have seen the following questions already:

- [Php - explode a string with two delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636689/php-explode-a-string-with-two-delimiters)
- [explode an array of delimited strings into two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714188/explode-an-array-of-delimited-strings-into-two-arrays)
- [PHP explode/split with 2 different delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16306112/php-explode-split-with-2-different-delimiters)

And more. If I have an input like this:

```
A@B#C
a@b#c
```

For each line, I have the two delimiters `@` and `#`, I would like to have them separated as an array this way:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
)

Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
)
```

I have the looping code this way:

```
foreach (explode(PHP_EOL, $input) as $line) {
    $line = explode("@", $line);
    $line[1] = explode("#", $line[1]);
}
```

I know what I am doing is wrong. The output I get is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => C
        )
)

Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
            [1] => c
        )
)
```

I am out of ideas to think anything else, so, can someone please guide me on how to split the string inside the same array? ps: I don't wanna use [regex](/questions/tagged/regex)!

Comment: Is the input 1 string or 2?

Comment: @Rizier123 I don't understand. What do you mean by 1 or 2?

Comment: Is it this: `$input1 = "A@B#C"; $input2 = "a@b#c";` or is it this: `$input = "A@B#C
a@b#c";`

Comment: @Rizier123 Assume for a single line. Check the full code now. It is on a loop! `:)`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you want to use an array?

Comment: @GregBurghardt What else can be better ways?

Comment: Wow. Just realized how tired i am and that i need some sleep. I meant to say "why don't you want to use _regular expressions_" :) Sheesh. Heading to bed.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Oh yeah. Now only even I understood your question. Even I need sleep buddy! Okay, `regex` is too mainstream to use! `:P`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred solution would be to use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), but since the question explicitly forbids the use of regex, how about just doing this:

```
$line = explode("#", str_replace("@", "#", $line));
```

So basically, just replace all occurrences of delimiter 1 with delimiter 2 and then split on delimiter 2.